# unable to install DPDK in Devstack(in Ubuntu 16.04 version)

Tags: openstack, devstack, dpdk, openvswitch

I am trying to install Devstack with DPDK in Ubuntu 16.04. I have installed Devstack (Rocky version) in Ubuntu machine. 
Reference link to install the devstack is mentioned below. 
https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/

Devstack was successfully installed. However, i am trying to validate DPDK in it. 
When i check the status of both DPDK and openvswitch. It is showing the status of openvswitch alone.

Can anyone, please let me know how to install dpdk manually or along with Devstack?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried devstack with ovs-dpdk, but if you are using ovs which is compiled with dpdk, then you can start from 'setup Hugepage' section in following doc manually:
http://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/intro/install/dpdk/

I also notice networking-ovs-dpdk plugin which can be used in devstack.
https://opendev.org/x/networking-ovs-dpdk/src/branch/master/doc/source/usage.rst